# Type latex questions using onlyoffice

Tags: latex, formula, onlyoffice

It seems that currently OnlyOffice offers the possibility to type directly latex formulas but I can't seem to make ir work and the official documentation does not solve my problem.

I tried clicking on "insert", then "formula", then in the little expand menu, I click on the button that says "{ } Latex" and I type a latex formula but nothing shows up. I tried for example

```
$4 \leq 5$
{4 \leq 5}
{$ 4\leq 5$}
```

and other variants. I must be mising something.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem so I experimented a bit and found that you can switch between the traditional formula view and the latex view by selecting the "Professional" and "Linear" options in that little floating menu. I don't think you need the dollar signs to delineate the equation.

So, type your Latex code in "Linear" mode and then view the equation in "Professional" mode I guess.

I've also noted that any formatting you do on the text in the equation, such as making any units non-italic is lost when switching between these modes.